# How to adjust a counter depending on whether or not we are inside a section or subsection

Tags: sectioning, environments, counters, tcolorbox

I want to create an `exercise` environment that can be used in either section, subsection, etc. As an illustration, consider the following:

- when in section 1, the third example should be titled as **Example 1.3**, but
- when in section 1 and subsection 2, the third example should be titled as **Example 1.2.3**.

How to do this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newcounter{exercise}
\newenvironment{exercise}
{\par\smallskip\refstepcounter{exercise}\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Exercise \thesection.\thesubsection.\theexercise]\ignorespaces}
{\end{tcolorbox}\par\smallskip\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}
\section{Polynomial}
In this section we will study expressions in the following form.
\[
a_0 x^n + a_1 x^{n-1} \cdots + a_n
\]
where \ldots
\begin{exercise}
Is $\frac{x-1}{2}$ a polynomial?
\tcblower
Yes. Because it can be rewritten as $x/2-1/2$.
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}
Is $0$ a polynomial?
\tcblower
Yes.
\end{exercise}
\subsection{Order}
The highest exponent in polynomial terms represents the order of  the polynomial.
\begin{exercise}
What is the order of $2x^3-3x^5+1$?
\tcblower
The highest exponent is 5 so the polynomial order is 5.
\end{exercise}
\end{document}
```

I did as follows but the output has double subsection when I am in subsection.

```
\newcounter{exercise}
\newenvironment{exercise}
{\par\smallskip\refstepcounter{exercise}\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Exercise \thesection\ifnum\value{subsection}>0.\thesubsection\fi.\theexercise]\ignorespaces}
{\end{tcolorbox}\par\smallskip\ignorespacesafterend}
```

### Note:

Best practice suggestions are welcome to make the environment more and more sophisticated such as it can be referenced by label, etc, etc...

Comment: Oh... i got it...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

You want to put the prefix in `\theexercise` so it is seen by `\ref` not just in the title.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newcounter{exercise}[subsection]
\renewcommand\theexercise{%
\thesection.%
\ifnum\value{subsection}>0 \arabic{subsection}.\fi
\arabic{exercise}}

\newenvironment{exercise}
{\par\smallskip\refstepcounter{exercise}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Exercise \theexercise]\ignorespaces}
{\end{tcolorbox}\par\smallskip\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}
\section{Polynomial}
In this section we will study expressions in the following form.
\[
a_0 x^n + a_1 x^{n-1} \cdots + a_n
\]
where \ldots
\begin{exercise}
Is $\frac{x-1}{2}$ a polynomial?
\tcblower
Yes. Because it can be rewritten as $x/2-1/2$.
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}
Is $0$ a polynomial?
\tcblower
Yes.
\end{exercise}
\subsection{Order}
The highest exponent in polynomial terms represents the order of  the polynomial.
\begin{exercise}
What is the order of $2x^3-3x^5+1$?
\tcblower
The highest exponent is 5 so the polynomial order is 5.
\end{exercise}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Refinement](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108671/16967) added as answer (too long for a comment).

Answer (score 6):

Refinement for [David Carlisle's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108653/16967), it is too long for a comment:

```
\newcounter{exercise}[subsection]
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{exercise}{section}
\makeatother

\renewcommand\theexercise{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}>0 %
    \thesubsection
  \else
    \thesection
  \fi
  .\arabic{exercise}%
}
```

Remarks:

- `\newcounter{exercise}[subsection]` only resets the counter for new `\subsections`, not for `\section`. An additional `\@addtoreset{exercise}{section}` is needed.
- Inside `\theexercise` I have used `\thesubsection` instead of `\arabic{subsection}`, then a change in `\thesubsection` is automatically reflected in `\theexercise`, e.g. if someone wants to have a different numbering style for subsections than the default.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can compare the subsection counter to zero (e.g. using commands from the `etoolbox`) and use this to decide how to compose the number.