# How do I reset the counter of a theorem tcolorbox after declaring a new section?

Tags: sectioning, tcolorbox, counters

Similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108642/235428), but how do I make it using `\newtcbtheorem`? I want to avoid duplicates on names since it gives warnings.

For example, the definition on the first section will have a name `tcb@cnt@dfn.1`, I think. Then, as I declare another section and make another definition, it will have the same name, thus the  duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
It's pretty simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{dfn}{Definition}{}{}

\begin{document}
\section{First Section}
\begin{dfn}{}{}
    Here is a definition
\end{dfn}
\begin{dfn}{}{}
    Here is a second definition
\end{dfn}
\section{A New Section}
\begin{dfn}{}{}
    Here is a third definition
\end{dfn}
\end{document}
```

The `number within` key sets the number to reset each time you call `\section`. Or to have the numbering change with every subsection use `number within=subsection`.

Comment: That is what I used, though it seems that the count for the second section is a _duplicate_ of the first section.

Comment: I don't know how should I make the MWE since I made one, but it worked. The warning is like this: `pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{tcb@cnt@df
n.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.148 ...begin{dfn}{Integration by Substitution}{}`, by the way.

Comment: Since you are getting an error your MWE should be code that someone can copy and paste and recreate the same error. This means you need a `\documentclass`, both `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`, all relevant packages (but not irrelevant packages) and the minimal code required in the document to cause the error to occur.

Comment: I know how to make an MWE but the problem is that I don't know where the problem occurred. Your example is exactly what I did in the first place and yet, the compiler treats the tcolorboxes as duplicates.

Comment: I recommend copying and pasting your work into a new document. If the issue persists delete parts of the code and recompile until either the error disappears or the output no longer shows what you want, add that section back in. Use what you are left with as an MWE.

Answer (score 0):

This errors probably comes from the use of `hyperref` package. It automatically creates links between labelled elements and references to them, but all labels must be different.

Every `dfn` created from `tcolorbox` definition, automatically creates a label with the prefix fixed in last parameter in `\newtcbtheorem` definition and the second mandatory parameter in each `\begin{dfn}{}{}`. If prefix and suffix are empty every definition will have a similar label and hyperref will show the error message.

I suggest to use something like this to avoid the error message:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{dfn}{Definition}{}{dfn}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{First Section}
\begin{dfn}{}{a}
    Here is a definition
\end{dfn}
\begin{dfn}{}{b}
    Here is a second definition
\end{dfn}
\section{A New Section}
\begin{dfn}{}{c}
    Here is a third definition
\end{dfn}

This is the first definition: \ref{dfn:a}, this is the second, \ref{dfn:b} and this the last one, \ref{dfn:c}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I remember doing this, but I guess I'll try to do it again. Maybe it will work now.